# How to establish requirements for a virtual machine for running a kind of MES system

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, asp.net-mvc

I want to upgrade my existing VM to (Windows Server, more RAM, better CPU, etc) - but I do not know how to evaluate current needs.

I am not a software engineer :) and I need your help in defining the proper configuration for a VM.

**This is the VM which I have in this moment. (Windows 7)**

[image]

**About the application running on this VM:**

I build a Web Application MVC 5 and I installed on above VM on my company server.

The application contains >50 MvcControllers (>100 Views) and several ApiControllers.
The api controllers are used for receiving or sending data every **15 seconds**. (on the same VM I have a worker service which is reading data from approx. 40 PLC every 15 sec, when found new value is passing the value to the WebApp to be saved in Sql Express database).
I have in production >60 devices (tablets and TVs) calling the ApiControllers to get fresh data every 1 min.

In the last 2 weeks I saw very often the cpu of current VM going to 100%, no change in code, only the number of devices (+20 tables on the shop floor).

Looking for CPU usage, I found from time to time the w3wp.exe up to 98% (in IIS Manger the CPU of the WebApp was also >90%) -> was clear that my webapp was the cause of this.

My assumption is that the number of devices matter :), is the only link which I could think at (I do not have somebody in IT department which can help).

I have not probleme with memory (VM is using approx 2.4 GbRam out of 8).

**So, can you give me some hints on how should I establish the requirements for a new VM?**

What is the trigger which I need to follow in order to establish if I need a better VM?

[image]